# Azure Cluster Startup time in Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that has 10 Dataflow activities and each uses AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime default integration cluster.

When I trigger the pipeline, cluster startup takes around 4 mins for each Dataflow totalling 40 mins to complete pipeline execution. Can I avoid this? If so, how?

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to either put those data flows on your pipeline canvas without dependency lines so that they all run in parallel, or set a TTL in your Azure IR and use that same Azure IR for each activity. This way, each subsequent activity can use a warm pool and start-up in 1-2 mins instead of 4 mins.

[Here is an explanation of these different methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview#azure-integration-runtime-and-data-flow-strategies).

[And here is how to configure TTL to set a warm pool for your factory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT_2ZV3a7Fc).

Comment: So there is no way I can have 0 cluster start up time for the rest of the Dataflows? Does Microsoft bill for the cluster startup time?

Comment: 0 startup time? But a cluster has to be started to do its work. In debug mode, you start/stop a cluster so that it's already hot when you're previewing data. When running jobs, Databricks uses a job per cluster model.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks Mark. One last question. Does Microsoft bill for the cluster startup time?

Comment: You are billed for the complete pipeline time E2E prorated to the min. So, if your pipeline takes 10 mins to execute, you are bill just for the 10 mins, not the full hour. For data flows, that time includes the "acquiring cluster" resource time.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT What is the pre-warmed Cluster *doing* for 1-2 minutes when you start the 2nd, 3rd, etc. Dataflow?

Comment: It utilizes Databrick's "Warm Pool" feature. That means that the cluster *resources*, i.e. the VM and networking resources, are warm, but the Databricks cluster still has to rehydrate and set-up the execution queue again. In ADF, we're going to improve upon this limitation and make that experience better with a new feature landing in a few more iterations.